# Cambiar con que valores se carga un Datalist (HTML/PHP)

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una tabla (html) donde cargo los datos que saco de una consulta en php:

```
<table>
     <?php foreach($consulta as $clave=>$valor): ?>
     <tr><td><?= $valor['nombre']; ?> </td></tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Bueno, ahora en vez de la columna nombre, me gustaria cargar otra, por ejemplo "direccion". Pero, sin realizar otra pagina, hay alguna manera de que este contenido sea dinamico? Por ejemplo poner un boton que cambie el dato que se muestra en la tabla. No se si es posible

Comment: Intenta usar codigo y no imagenes para mostrar tu pregunta.

Comment: Al momento de presionar el botón que acción sucederá? añadirá un dato nuevo o actualizará la lista simplemente ? Si se trata de un dato nuevo me imagino que es con un input para que ingrese el nombre y luego el botón enviar, y eso se sume a la lista?